# How can i call multiple object from array and each one object has it own properties?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some balls (let say 10 balls) on stage with the same instance names "ball" and 4 floors downfloor upfloor rightfloor and leftfloor.
The balls bounce on the floors and everything works good.
Now if the ball hit  the enemy i want to spawn another ball with the same properties as ball from a new Array.i try it but when the first ball spawn it bouncing but when another ball hit the enemy the second ball wich is spawn has the same properties with the first ball and not it own properties.

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();


var downFloorArray:Array = new Array();
for (var df:int = numChildren - 1; df>= 0; df--)
{
    var childdf:DisplayObject = getChildAt(df);
    if (childdf.name == "downFloor")
    {
        downFloorArray.push(MovieClip(childdf));
    }
}

var rightFloorArray:Array = new Array();
for (var rf:int = numChildren - 1; rf>= 0; rf--)
{
    var childrf:DisplayObject = getChildAt(rf);
    if (childrf.name == "rightFloor")
    {
        rightFloorArray.push(MovieClip(childrf));
    }
}

var leftFloorArray:Array = new Array();
for (var lf:int = numChildren - 1; lf>= 0; lf--)
{
    var childlf:DisplayObject = getChildAt(lf);
    if (childlf.name == "leftFloor")
    {
        leftFloorArray.push(MovieClip(childlf));
    }
}

var upFloorArray:Array = new Array();
for (var uf:int = numChildren - 1; uf>= 0; uf--)
{
    var childuf:DisplayObject = getChildAt(uf);
    if (childuf.name == "upFloor")
    {
        upFloorArray.push(MovieClip(childuf));
    }
}

var ballArray:Array = new Array();
for (var b:int = numChildren - 1; b>= 0; b--)
{
    var childb:DisplayObject = getChildAt(b);
    if (childb.name == "ball")
    {
        ballArray.push(MovieClip(childb));
        MovieClip(childb).ballY = 20;
        MovieClip(childb).ballX = 3;
    }
}







stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameLoop);
function gameLoop(event:Event):void
{
    for (var sab:int=ballArray.length-1; sab>=0; sab--)
    {
        ballArray[sab].ballY--;
        ballArray[sab].x +=  ballArray[sab].ballX;
        ballArray[sab].y -=  ballArray[sab].ballY;
        for (var sadf:int=downFloorArray.length-1; sadf>=0; sadf--)
        {
            if (downFloorArray[sadf].hitTestPoint(ballArray[sab].x,ballArray[sab].y + 27))
            {
                ballArray[sab].ballY = 20;
            }
        }
        for (var sarf:int=rightFloorArray.length-1; sarf>=0; sarf--)
        {
            if (rightFloorArray[sarf].hitTestPoint(ballArray[sab].x + 20,ballArray[sab].y))
            {
                ballArray[sab].ballX = -3;
            }
        }
        for (var salf:int=leftFloorArray.length-1; salf>=0; salf--)
        {
            if (leftFloorArray[salf].hitTestPoint(ballArray[sab].x - 20,ballArray[sab].y))
            {
                ballArray[sab].ballX = 3;
            }
        }
        for (var sauf:int=upFloorArray.length-1; sauf>=0; sauf--)
        {
            if                       `(upFloorArray[sauf].hitTestPoint(ballArray[sab].x,ballArray[sab].y - 27))`
            {
                ballArray[sab].ballY = -3;
            }
        }
        if (ballArray[sab].hitTestObject(enemy))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the new ball has the same properties as the original? You mean like its motion copies the original instead of bouncing uniquely of relevant objects?

Comment: Yes , thats right.i try to make the new balls to bouncing over floors..

Comment: Show the code where you instantiate new balls

Comment: if (ballArray[sab].hitTestObject(enemy))
  {
   var ba:ball2 = new ball2  ;
   ball1Array.push(ba);
   this.addChild(ba);
   ba.x = enemy.x;
   ba.y = enemy.y;
   enemy.x = enemy.x + 100;
  }

Comment: Ok i understand what to  do.I must to put the properties i want under the line that i create the new balls.Correct?

Comment: @SavvasAnt That's correct.